# Работа с модулями Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Добрый день!

Я в store динамически добавляю (registerModule) и уничтожаю (unregisterModule) модуль А. В модуле А есть долгая экшн с AJAX запросом, по окончании которой вызывается мутация в модуле А.

Проблема в том, пользователь может удалить модуль во время выполнения экшна, и я получаю ошибку

```
[vuex] unknown local mutation type: LOADED, global type: moduleA_qn55dznhk/LOADED
```

Я могу как-нибудь перед удалением модуля принудительно завершить выполняющийся экшн и очистить все ресурсы/события?

Comment: Пока на ум приходит только держать в модуле признак активности (менять его при уничтожении модуля), с учетов которого выхывать/не вызывать коммиты. Но не уверен, что при завершении экшина все ресурсы освободятся

Answer (score 1):

У меня ответ не сколько про модули vuex, сколько про возможность отменить выполняющиеся асинхронные AJAX-запросы.
Можно в момент уничтожения модуля (unregisterModule) отменить все выполняемые в данный момент запросы из модуля.

Удобно это сделать, например, через [Cancelation Token в axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation).
По идее это потребует не много переделок: создать токен отмены, во все запросы указывать его, в момент уничтожения модуля вызвать отмену. Ещё в самих запросах можно обработать ошибку, которая возникнет при отмене.